# How to center an absolute positioned item vertically?

Tags: css, position, css-position

I would like to align an absolute positioned div. Top:50%, bottom:50% not working, what's the solution for this?

CSS

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
}

#cen {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:grey;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="cen"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2xq5F/

Comment: `top:50%` sets the top edge of the element to be 50% down from the top of its first non-statically positioned parent.

Answer (score 3):

To center something vertically, you need do add a `top: 50%` and a negative `margin-top: -(elementHeight/2)`.

In your case it will be

```
#cen {
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:grey;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it this way:

```
#cen {
    position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background:grey;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EBmy3/

Big advantage, no math required.

However, this works because you specified width and height.  This gets trickier when you use percentages.

Note: I made the blocks half the size so they fit in the fiddle window... will also work with the larger blocks.

**Works Well With Replaced Elements**

This technique does a pretty good job if you are positioning an image, which has specific dimensions (though you may not know them).

See example in fiddle.

Comment: How compatible is this with older browsers?

Comment: This is actually out of the CSS 2.1 spec, so it could work as far back as IE6, but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment is based off of other inline elements. The best way I've found to vertically align something is to add a psuedo class.

It's easy to vertically align something if you know the dimensions, like some of the other answers have noted. It makes it harder though, when you don't have specific dimensions and needs to be more free.

Basically, the method aligns the psuedo class with the rest of the content to align middle whatever is inside the container.

```
div#container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  text-align:center;
}
div#container:before {
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
div#cen {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I kind of like this, quite clever actually.  It is not exactly perfect, but it does a pretty good job.  Please see the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8Gbkh/, you can see that the child div is not quite in the center.  I think the generated content takes up a bit of space.  However, this trick will work when many others will fail and it is good to know.

Comment: text-align:center the container

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you need it to be absolutely positioned for, but if you trick CSS into thinking your container is a table-cell, you can use the vertical-align property for a fully dynamic layout.

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#cen {
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are the real measurements, why not just do this?

```
#cen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 150px;
    background:grey;
}
```

Comment: The instant any environment variable changes or content dynamically alters the flow, this will break.  `top:50%` and a negative margin are more efficient than hard coded values.

Comment: Except the fact that your negative margin is also hard coded, so ultimately you're writing more code for the same result. Seems like an anti-pattern to me.

Comment: I don't know why there is a downvote on this answer. I prefere the sollution with `top: 50%;` and a negative margin too but this is still a sollution that works for that particular case.

Comment: Not sure about the downvote either. I don't see the point in the `top: 50%;` answer for this particular case. You could use `top: 25%;` to achieve the result without using any negative margin.

Comment: Yes it's just more dynamic if the container height changes but for that particular case you're definitely right.

Comment: @Finbarr Not quite.  The height and the margin are both set values.  Both of these are contained within the element itself and are not dependent on anything outside of that element.  If you hard code the top value, however, it will break if you alter the wrapping container.  If that wrapping container is hard coded too, you will have to change all three items if the topmost one needs changed.  If, however you make your styling adaptable to it's environment, you will not have as many headaches in the future.  a good resource on this would be Bulletproof Web Design by Dan Cederholm.

Comment: @JosephMarikle it seems the only benefit of the solution with `top: 50%;` is when the height of the containing element changes - you _may_ not need to change the declarations for the contained element in this case. In the `top: 150px;` solution, when the height of the topmost element changes you'd need to change the `top` declaration of the child element only. In the case where the change in the height of the containing element would require a dimension change of the child element, all 3 values would need to be changed with both solutions anyway so it is a very slight advantage.

Comment: @JosephMarikle anyway, you'll note that I qualified my answer by saying "If those are the real measurements...". And I'm done with discussing the minutiae of css positioning for today.